# Python AssertionError 'height' must be length 0 or scalar Bar(arange) function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Whats the problem here? Using 2.7. Thanks.

This is the error:

AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 0 or scalar

```
from numpy import zeros, random

m=zeros(10,int)
for i in range(10000):
    n=random.random()
    if 0.0<=n and n<0.1: m[0]=m[0]+1
    if 0.1<=n and n<0.2: m[1]=m[1]+1
    if 0.2<=n and n<0.3: m[2]=m[2]+1
    if 0.3<=n and n<0.4: m[3]=m[3]+1
    if 0.4<=n and n<0.5: m[4]=m[4]+1
    if 0.5<=n and n<0.6: m[5]=m[5]+1
    if 0.6<=n and n<0.7: m[6]=m[6]+1
    if 0.7<=n and n<0.8: m[7]=m[7]+1
    if 0.8<=n and n<0.9: m[8]=m[8]+1
    if 0.9<=n and n<1.0: m[9]=m[9]+1
print m

from pylab import *
bar(arange(0.1,0.1),m,width=0.1)
#show()
savefig('5.4graph.png')
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your `arange` call in the call to `bar`. You're calling `arange(0.1,0.1)` which will yield an empty array. I think you wanted to type `arange(0, 1, 0.1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should accomplish what you want, though it might not make complete sense to you:

```
# this does pretty much what you're trying to do with your for loop
m = map(lambda x: (random.random()/10)+1+.1*x,range(10))
print m
bar(arange(10)+.1,m)
show()
#or savefig('test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, i actually did it myself like this, see below

Comment: Nice, glad you got it figured out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



x = np.random.random(1000000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(x,25,normed=True)
ax1.set_title('Distribution from random numbers')

#plt.show()


plt.savefig('histogram1.png')
```